# Is there a way through which I can append the new list into the existing list on each while iteration?

Tags: python, list, while-loop, scheduling

**Can someone please help me with a better way of doing it?

> This is my output.The user has to input whether he has a new process to enter if yes then enter new process and it must get appended to a new list.But in my case after every new iteration of while it gets appended to the first list instead.

---

```
Enter process name: 1
Enter process Arrival Time: 3
Enter Execution Time: 2

[['1', 3, 2]]
Enter process name: 2
Enter process Arrival Time: 4
Enter Execution Time: 3

[['1', 3, 2], ['2', 4, 3]]
enter new processy
ENTER TOTAL NUMBER OF PROCESSES: 1
Enter process name: 3
Enter process Arrival Time: 2
Enter Execution Time: 3

[['1', 3, 2, '3', 2, 3], ['2', 4, 3], []]
enter new process

----------------------------------------------
>This is my code 

a = 0
#p = [['p1', 0, 2], ['p2', 1, 2], ['p3', 5, 3], ['p4', 6, 4]]
a2 = [0]
completion_time=[]
pp = []
tat=[]
waiting_time=[]
p = []
total_wtime = 0
n=0

def addnew():
    n = int(input('ENTER TOTAL NUMBER OF PROCESSES: '))
    for i in range(n):
        p.append([])
        p[i].append(input('Enter process name: '))
        p[i].append(int(input('Enter process Arrival Time: ')))

        p[i].append(int(input('Enter Execution Time: ')))
        print('')
        print(p)

ans="y"
while(ans=="y"):
    addnew()
    ans = input("enter new process")
```

Comment: It is sometimes tempting to change a list while you are looping over it; however, it is often simpler and safer to create a new list instead. 
See (Looping Techniques)[https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques]
**Never, ever change a list while iterating it.**

Comment: Kudos for paying attention!  You got a better answer after mine, and took the trouble to switch the "best answer" choice.  This will be helpful to future Stack Overflow users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index variable `i` is looping from `0` to `n-1` every time, even when you are adding elements an existing list.

The best approach is probably just to add new elements to a new list, and then append that, as Prune suggested.  But if you are looking for the minimal change to your existing code, then change the line:

```
    for i in range(n):
```

to

```
    for i in range(len(p), len(p) + n):
```

And this will ensure that when you call `addnew` again, the indices keep going from where you left off, rather than starting at 0 again.

---

If you *do* decide to adopt the approach of appending to a new list (see Prune's answer), then an additional change that you could consider, given that your variable `i` would no longer be used inside the loop, would be to call it `_` instead of `i`, because this is conventional naming for dummy variables.  This is not applicable to your existing code because you are using it to index `p`.

---

And here is also another alternative...

You could change your `p[i]` to `p[-1]` (i.e. the *last* element) wherever it occurs. Then again your loop variable is a dummy variable only, and it may as well loop from `0` to `n-1` as at present, because we don't care what the values are provided that there are `n` iterations.

```
    for _ in range(n):
        p.append([])
        p[-1].append(input('Enter process name: '))
        p[-1].append(int(input('Enter process Arrival Time: ')))
        # ... etc ...
```

Again, this is only a suggestion for minimal change from existing code. The cleanest approach is still the `newlist` one.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, on every call to `addnew`, you append a new empty list, but then you return to the first list to append the new data.  Instead of accessing `p[i]` from 0 to `n`, you have to deal only with the new list.  Once you have all of the new data, *then* append the resulting new list to the end of `p`.

```
def addnew():
    n = int(input('ENTER TOTAL NUMBER OF PROCESSES: '))
    for i in range(n):
        newlist = []
        newlist.append(input('Enter process name: '))
        newlist.append(int(input('Enter process Arrival Time: ')))

        newlist.append(int(input('Enter Execution Time: ')))
        print('')
        print(newlist)
    p.append(newlist)
```